# Automatic like when using login with Facebook

Tags: android, ios, facebook, sdk

I just implemented the login with Facebook SDK on a mobile app I developed for both Android and iOS, and was wondering if it's possible to have my users like my Facebook page as part of the login. In other words, can I have my users both login with Facebook and like my page with the same click?

Comment: I dont think there is any api available to do this, but look at https://developers.facebook.com/. may be you will find some solution for it

Comment: No, and to try to do so would be against Facebook's platform policies.

Answer (score 0):

That will be a violation of Facebook's platform policies. Another thing that might be worth noting is that 'liking' an object will probably require '`publish_actions`' permission from the user which means you will have to [submit your app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review) for review.